# Create new column with name of City from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, api, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I have the following problem, I need to create a column with the name of the City but I only have the values of longitude and latitude in Python.

What would you recommend me to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with the help of Google Maps Api, request example is below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

[Official Tutorail](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#place-id) go for Example of Reverse Geocoding section.

After you get all answers from Google API and find Place names there, put them in a list, then do:

`df["NewColumn"] = the list`

Hope it was useful for you, happy coding!